# Как нарисовать при помощи canvas древо?

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь нарисовать что-то вроде этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
     public class Tree extends View {
    Paint paint;
    Path path;

    public  Tree(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public  Tree(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();

    }

    public Tree(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
              paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(50, 50);
    path.lineTo(50, 500);
    path.lineTo(200, 500);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    }

}
```

на деле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Полдела сделано. А в чем возникла проблема?

Comment: @ Nofate
не понимаю, как нарисовать ветви выше

Comment: Точно так же. Координаты начала, координаты конца.

Comment: @Nofate
`path.lineTo(x, y); `  но только ниже тех что максимальные?

Comment: указал и ничего не изменилось:
`path.moveTo(50, 50);`
        `path.lineTo(50, 500);`
        `path.lineTo(100, 500);`
        `path.lineTo(200, 500);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
        path.moveTo(50, 50);
        path.lineTo(50, 500);
        path.moveTo(50, 100);
        path.lineTo(100, 100);
        path.moveTo(50, 200);
        path.lineTo(200, 200);
```

Вот что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так далее - рисуйте ветки дальше. Суть в том нужно переставлять курсор: метод `moveTo` ставит «курсор» в указанную точку, и далее рисование пойдет от нее.

Comment: понял,буду пробовать!Благодарю!